# Extension of UIBarButtonItem when touchesBegan

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am working actually on management of connection with a ReachabilityManager class.

I have created a toast which show when connection is lost and recovered.
I also created two extensions (UIButton and UISwitch) and on it I override func touchesBegan to check and play action of button/switch or to show the toast with error message only (and don't play selector of button/switch).

Here my UIButton extension to understand:

```
extension UIButton {
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if ReachabilityManager.shared.reachability.connection == .none {
            ReachabilityManager.shared.customConnectionToast(ToastStyle.connectionLost.applyStyle(),
                                  description: NSLocalizedString("no_connection_error_message", comment: ""))
        } else {
            sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.allTouchEvents)
        }
    }
}
```

I need now to create the same extension for UIBarButtonItem but the problem is there is no touchesBegan action for this object and I don't know how to make something similar to UIbutton and UISwitch extensions. Another information on why I want that is that I can't refactor all barbutton items of the app (it will take me 2 weeks). It's for that I have to find a way with extension or something else but absolutely a generic solution.

If anyone has any idea I would be grateful.

In advance thank you.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution: Use `UIButton` and make that a `UIBarButtonItem`, then you can use your category above you posted (extension of UIButton) to your new button acting as a barButtonItem.

Like so:

```
internal lazy var button_Close: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(.close, for: .normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: -30, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(back(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

Make it a barButton item:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.button_Close)
    self.button_Close.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55.0, height: 44.0)
    let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        negativeSpacer.width = -30
    }
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, barButton]
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Glenn for your quick answer but the problem is that the application is big and I can't refactor all barbutton items of the app (it will take me 2 weeks) I have to find a way with extension or something else but absolutely a generic solution.

Comment: Welp, I'm afraid you have no choice but to use this approach. I hope theres' another way and I would like to know that too. :)